# keystore was tampered with or password was incorrect?

Tags: android, certificate, keytool, android-keystore

**Format My computer** I copy my work space backup after I put my work space in my c/user/pcname/ past here
"**i upgrade my application and export my password is not incorrect that give me message keystore was tampered with or password was incorrect?**" what to do ? give me full description step by step i am new in android.

Comment: Are you exporting app from some keystore?

Comment: i want to update my app but now give me the msg keystore was tempered with or password was incorrect

Comment: Is the error coming when you try to export the apk?

Comment: no application is working very good no error

Comment: Are you able to export apk?

Comment: already my app is in play store now i want to update so i put password in my key they give me msg that i put in my description

Comment: Which language are u comfortable in?

Comment: hindi language comfortable

Comment: Ok tell me in hindi in comments about the problem.

Comment: mene system format kiya to mene workspace ki backup le li format karne ke bad mene workspace jha thi vha hi rakh di or eclipse start kiya ab project barabar import ho gye koi error nai aai uske bad mene ek application upgrade kari or use export karrha hu purani key ka password jo dala tha vhi dala to keystore was tampered with or password was incorrect esa msg aa rha he...

Comment: export to sing in kar rha hu tab purani key he uska jo password he vhi dal rha hu to bhi esa msg aa rha he

Comment: keystore save kiya tha?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The password you are entering is wrong. Please check it again.

Comment: @Minato, I have the same error. **Keystore was tampered with or password was incorrect**.
I can generate apk file, but can not run a project. When I run a project, getting this error.

Comment: @Mr.AbduJan On running a project?

Comment: @Minato, yes. When I run a project getting this error: **Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> Failed to read key domainname.tj from store "/home/name/AndroidStudioProjects/Projectname/extras/KeyStore/keystorefile.jks": Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect**